# $P (A ∩ B) = P (A) ∪ P (B)$ implies that $A = B?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A and B be sets. How to prove that $P (A ∩ B) = P (A) ∪ P (B)$  implies that $A = B$

So far:

Since $P (A ∩ B)= P(A)∩(B)$

My hypothesis is $x \in P(A)∩(B)= x\in P (A) ∪ P (B)$, isn´t it?

So $x\subseteq A$ and $x\subseteq B= x\subseteq A$ or $x\subseteq B$

Is this enough to prove $A = B$??

Am I proving logically correct?

Comment: $A \in P(A) \cup P(B)$.  So now answer this: what does it mean if $A \in P(A\cap B)$?

Comment: A∈P(A∩B) -> A⊆(A∩B)->A⊆A and A⊆B

Comment: Your argument is correct. Just two pieces of advice. Fristly, be careful about the way you write down your proof. The way you use the equals sign in lines 4 and 5 (as a logical equivalence) is illigitimate and makes it difficult to understand your argument. Secondly, to some people your argument will be detailed enough, for others it won't. But when you, the author, don't see whether your argument is complete, as in this case, it's a sign that you should elaborate further (see @GEdgar's comment).

Comment: how would you elaborate more? My doubt is in : So x⊆A and x⊆B=x⊆A or x⊆B